# Synchronize objects across $scope without a service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am trying to get a piece of code to work where I don't have total control over half of the code.  In short, there is 1 main controller that has an object that is then obtained from a second controller.  When main controller 1 updates the object, controller 2 never sees it.  I think this is because the 2 controllers aren't watching the object/properties (copies?).  If you notice, the Angular Binding to {{Title}}, this is where the issue is visible as the "Title" never gets updated in the second controller.

Here is some sample code that shows the problem.  Currently, the code does a 3 seconds loop to get the object again, and reassign it to the second controller.

The code here I can't really touch.  I have source, but it spaghetti and I am just generalizing what is here.

```
// html I can't really change, outside my world.
<div id="mainApp" ng-app="MainApp" ng-controller="mainController">
</div>

// code I can't "really" change, non-angular (can't use $http).
$ajax(get...)
.success(function (result) {
    $('#element').html(result);
})
```

The code below is fairly separated and I can tinker with it.  The HTML is returned from a service called by the $ajax call above.

```
// code I can change (the "result", or html returned from the service)
// containerController.js
var containerController = function ($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.models = {
      item: null;
   }

   $scope.getItem = function() {
      var mainAppScope = angular.element($('#mainApp')).scope();
      $scope.models.item = mainAppScope.GetItem();
   }

   $scope.getItem();

    // HACK WORK AROUND
    // Get the item from the mainController.
    var itemSync = setInterval(function () {
    $scope.getItem();
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 3000);
}
```

The HTML returned from the service (it's really an ASP.NET MVC Partial View)

```
// HTML
<div id="container" ng-app="containerApp" ng-controller="containerController">
    <!-- This will bind the first time, but won't syncronize when other controller updates -->
    <!-- the controller is currently doing a loop to do so, not good. -->
    <div>{{models.item.Title}}</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/controllers/containerController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // This will inject the controller and new app into angular.
    var container = document.getElementById('container');

    var containerApp = angular.module('containerApp', []);

    containerApp.controller('containerController', ['$scope', containerController]);

    angular.bootstrap(angular.element(container), ['containerApp']);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change hacky part to use `$interval` which will manage to run digest cycle after each interval

```
var itemSync = $interval(function () {
   $scope.getItem();
}, 3000);
```

To sync object from parent controller to child controller you could use object structure of model, that will is nothing but [**Javascript prototypal**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) & will update data.

```
$scope.pageData = {}; //declare this in parent controller
$scope.pageData.title = 'Title 1' //use this where you want to change in child controller
```